# External keyboard event handlers stop responding

Tags: android, react-native, keyboard

I've been working on a project which needs to capture keystrokes from an external keyboard (a handheld barcode scanner really) anywhere in the app. Using react-native, this should be trivial, especially with the library [react-native-keyevent](https://github.com/kevinejohn/react-native-keyevent).

Works perfectly on the initial load. I then navigate to another part of the app (using react-navigation) and try to scan a barcode; nothing happens. I replaced the `react-native-keyevent` overrides `MainActivity.java` with some simple `Log.d("KeyEvents", "...")`, overriding `dispatchKeyEvent`, `onKeyUp`, `onKeyMultiple` and `onKeyDown`. I only log, then call super.

Same behaviour. Logs fine until I navigate, then it stops. After investigating the Android docs, it seems Views can override key handlers, and thereby 'steal' keystrokes. However I'm stuck finding out *which* view steals the focus. Also there's really no keyboard handling in react-native by default, so to my understanding, everything should be passed on to the activity.

Wandering hopelessly around in the react-native codebase, I stumbled upon `TVEventHandler` which  I use to log if a view requests focus:

```
import TVEventHandler from 'react-native/Libraries/Components/AppleTV/TVEventHandler';

(new TVEventHandler).enable('foo', function(){
    console.log(arguments);
})
```

Right before the handlers stop working, this line indeed logs some `focus` events with a view tag. However, I don't know how to find out which view has a certain tag.

Can someone point me in the right direction where to look?